# rect error-boundary doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-error-boundary

When using react-boundary and throw a manual error, the error-boundary works! The problem is, after 1-2 seconds it renders the error as if there wasn't an error-boundary

This is the code

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('has error', this.state);
    if ((this.state as any).hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

function Bomb(): any {
  const a = null;
  return <span>{a.b.c}</span>;
}

function App() {
  const [explode, setExplode] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setExplode((e) => !e)}>toggle explode</button>
      <ErrorBoundary>{explode ? <Bomb /> : null}</ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the behavior:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I just found out that it actually works properly. ErrorBoundary fallback is rendered and because NODE_ENV is set to development, debug overlay appears. When you set `display: none` to overlay iframe, you'll see expected "Something went wrong.".